# Scanning a list of items, and returning specific values

Tags: python, python-3.x

so for my program, this is a media lab that has various books and movies on stock. I wanted to implement many different options, and for one of them, I wanted for and was trying to implement the option of when the user presses 2, the program returns this information about the media store.

```
Inventory is worth $75.89
Most expensive item at $11.99
There are 5 Book(s), and 4 Movie(s)
```

This is what I am trying to do in my function info. I expressed what I wanted to do in words, but is there a way for like a loop to read through / scan the whole list and find these things about the catalog? I tried to create the function to print the inventory worth, but it hasn't gotten to work.

```
from MediaItem import MediaItem


def initialize():
    """Declares the list all_items and adds
    the initial MediaItem objects.
    Note that these data would come from a database in real-world
    applications. The data would then be represented in the program
    as MediaItem objects as below.
    """
    all_items = []
    # item 1
    item = MediaItem()
    item.media = "Movie"
    item.title = "2001: A Space Odyssey"
    item.price = 11.99
    item.ref = "TU2RL012"
    item.director = "Stanley Kubrick"
    item.lead_actor = "Keir Dullea"
    all_items = all_items + [item]
    # item 2
    item = MediaItem()
    item.media = "Book"
    item.title = "A Brief History of Time"
    item.price = 10.17
    item.ref = "GV5N32M9"
    item.author = "Stephen Hawking"
    all_items = all_items + [item]
    # item 3
    item = MediaItem()
    item.media = "Movie"
    item.title = "North by Northwest"
    item.price = 8.99
    item.ref = "1DB6HK3L"
    item.director = "Alfred Hitchcock"
    item.lead_actor = "Cary Grant"
    all_items = all_items + [item]
    # item 4
    item = MediaItem()
    item.media = "Movie"
    item.title = "The Good, The Bad and The Ugly"
    item.price = 9.99
    item.ref = "PO5T7Y89"
    item.director = "Sergio Leone"
    item.lead_actor = "Clint Eastwood"
    all_items = all_items + [item]
    # item 5
    item = MediaItem()
    item.media = "Book"
    item.title = "The Alchemist"
    item.price = 6.99
    item.ref = "TR3FL0EW"
    item.author = "Paulo Coelho"
    all_items = all_items + [item]
    # item 6
    item = MediaItem()
    item.media = "Book"
    item.title = "Thus Spoke Zarathustra"
    item.price = 7.81
    item.ref = "F2O9PIE9"
    item.author = "Friedrich Nietzsche"
    all_items = all_items + [item]
    # item 7
    item = MediaItem()
    item.media = "Book"
    item.title = "Jonathan Livingston Seagull"
    item.price = 6.97
    item.ref = "R399CED1"
    item.author = "Richard Bach"
    all_items = all_items + [item]
    # item 8
    item = MediaItem()
    item.media = "Movie"
    item.title = "Gone with the Wind"
    item.price = 4.99
    item.ref = "2FG6B3N9"
    item.director = "Victor Fleming"
    item.lead_actor = "Vivien Leigh"
    all_items = all_items + [item]
    # item 9
    item = MediaItem()
    item.media = "Book"
    item.title = "Gone with the Wind"
    item.price = 7.99
    item.ref = "6Y9OPL87"
    item.author = "Margarett Mitchell"
    all_items = all_items + [item]

    return all_items


def display_menu():
    """Prints the menu of options.
    No parameters, no return.
    """
    print("\nMenu");
    print("====");
    print("1-List Inventory");
    print("2-Info Inventory");
    print("3-List of All Books");
    print("4-List of All Movies");
    print("5-Item Description");
    print("6-Remove Item");
    print("7-Add Item");
    print("8-Set Maximum Price");
    print("0-Exit\n");


######## Implement all other functions listed below

def display(all_items, media="all"):
    """Prints all of the data for the MediaItems on the
    all_items list passed in. The parameter media is used
    to select for only "Book", "Movie", or, by default, "all".
    """
    print("Reference / Media / Title / Price")
    print("-----------------------------")
    for item in all_items:
        if media == "Book" and item.media == "Book":
            print(item.ref, "\t", item.media, "\t", item.title, "\t", item.price,)

        if media == "Movie" and item.media == "Movie":
            print(item.ref, "\t", item.media, "\t", item.title, "\t", item.price,)

        if media == "all":
            print(item.ref, "\t", item.media, "\t", item.title, "\t", item.price,)




 def info(all_items):
for item in all_items:
    if item.price == "Price":
        print("Inventory is worth", all_items.price)



def search_item(all_items, target_ref):
    """Searches the list of items in the all_items list passed in
    for a match on the reference field, target_ref.
    Returns the MediaItem object if a match is found, otherwise it
    returns None.
    """


def display_item(item):
    """Prints all of the data in the MediaItem object, item, passed in.
    """


def search_item_index(all_items, target_ref):
    """Searches the list all_items for a match on the reference
    field target_ref. Returns the index of the item that matches the target_ref,
    returns None if no match was found in the all_items.
    The index is zero-based.
    """


def create_item(media_type):
    """Creates a new MediaItem object and returns it.
    The argument media_type is either the string "Book" or "Movie".
    The function prompts the user for the data required for
    the type of media specified by the parameter media_type.
    """
```

Comment: i want to see your work/attempt before I give you the answer.  Thank you.

Comment: `all_items = all_items + [item]` ⇒ `all_items.append(item)` ([docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types))

Comment: Yeah @CristianCiupitu I know, the teacher wanted it like that because we haven't learned append yet

Comment: I'll try something now and i'll let you know @Fallenreaper.

Comment: @Fallenreaper here's something for the Inventory, not sure if its right, I get the idea of what has to happen but implementing it is whats not getting through to me.

Answer (score 0):

Break the problem down into smaller pieces.

```
Inventory is worth $75.89
Most expensive item at $11.99
There are 5 Book(s), and 4 Movie(s)
```

First, write code which only computes the `$75.89` in the line which says, "`Inventory is worth $75.89`" The following function, `sum_prices` will do that for us:

```
def sum_prices(all_items):
    count = 0
    for item in all_items:
        count = count + item.price
    return count
```

We can test `sum_prices` as follows:

```
full_catalog  = initialize()
inventory_value = sum_prices(full_catalog)
print(inventory_value)
```

It prints `75.89`. That works fine. Next, let's write some code which finds the most expensive price.

```
def get_highest_price(all_items):
    high_price = float("-inf")
    for item in all_items:
        if high_price < item.price:
            high_price = item.price
    return high_price
```

Below is some code which tests `get_highest_price`

```
full_catalog = initialize()
hp = get_highest_price(full_catalog)
print(hp)
```

The code above prints `11.99`, which seems to be the highest price.

We can also count the number of books and number of movies:

```
def count_media_type(all_items, media_type):
    count = 0
    for item in all_items:
        if item.media == media_type:
            count += 1
    return count

def count_books(all_items):
    return count_media_type(all_items, "Book")

def count_movie(all_items):
    return count_media_type(all_items, "Movie")
```

After you have all of the small pieces of the puzzle, you can put them together:

```
def print_stats(all_items):
    inv_value = sum_prices(all_items)
    high_price = get_highest_price(all_items)
    book_count = count_books(all_items)
    movie_count = count_movie(all_items)

    print("Inventory is worth $", inv_value)
    print("Most expensive item at $", high_price)
    print("There are", book_count, "Book(s) and", movie_count, "Movie(s)")
```

Comment: thanks for your response. what does the "-inf" inside of the float mean?

Comment: And, this code gives me an error in line 47, saying that there is a missing all_items argument where i have a comment.